# How to read entire message from the socket to reconstruct the object?

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm sending a message that is basically a serialized to xml object (SerializedXMLMessageObject ) from server to client.

I'm trying to read the entire message and accumulate it into the MemoryStream, before I can deserialize it. 
The problem I'm having is that it never gets into the 'else' part of this if-else below.
When it's done reading it skips to the end bracket of the else statement.

Two questions:

1. How do I read the entire message from the socket and remain connected to the server? 
   Is there an easy way to fix the code below or do I have to provide some sort of delimiter?
2. Where can I find examples of sending an xml serialized object via sockets in C#?
   every example that I come across shows how to send a simple string.

Edit 1: The expectation is that the connection remains open. I.e. the client stays connected to the server.

```
private void callback(IAsyncResult result)
 {
   byte[] data = (byte[])result.AsyncState;

            try
            {
                int read = socket.EndReceive(result);

                if (read > 0)
                {
                    _memoryStream.Write(data, 0, read);
                    socket.BeginReceive(data, 0, 255, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(callback), data);
                }

                else
                {
                    SerializedXMLMessageObject msg = DeserializeFromXml<SerializedXMLMessageObject >(_memoryStream.ToArray());

                }             

            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                socket.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is your expectation that the other side hold the socket open after sending it, or that they close the connection? I believe your read will only return 0 when they close the connection, otherwise it just won't return on the callback. My sockets are a bit rusty, but maybe you could just explain your expected request - response type of pattern for better assistance?

Comment: @Raptor563 - Good point, I didn't think of that, but yes the expectation is that the connection is still open.

Comment: As @Raptor563 said, you will get 0 bytes when the connection closes, since this is a stream. Your best bet is a delimiter or a header which says how many bytes to expect in the body.

Comment: The stream has no idea how big or small your "message" is.  As far as the stream is concerned, it is never ending and has no discrete "messages" in it.  It is up to you to communicate somehow when a "complete" message has been received.  As trydis mentioned, this could be accomplished by sending the expected number of bytes in a header that has a fixed number of bytes in it, or using special delimiters sent in the stream so you can discern where one message ends and another begins (since you could get one or more "messages" in at the same time, or you could receive a partial message).

Answer (score 1):

Took the advice and realized my own problem.

From the sending side I compute the message size to be send:

```
 byte[] data = ObjectToByteArray(SerializedXMLMessageObject);
 byte[] head = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length);
 byte[] total = new byte[data.Length + head.Length];
 head.CopyTo(total, 0);
 data.CopyTo(total, head.Length);

socket.Send(...)
```

On the receiving side I cast it to StateObject, extract the message size and read until it's finished.

`stateObject.TotalMessageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(stateObject.buffer, 0`);

......

```
 if (state.received < state.expected)           
 {
  handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.bufferSize,
                            SocketFlags.None, callback, stateobject);
 }
```